# Can't create object with relation one-to-many

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm a newbie in sequelize, so got some troubles with the trivial task. I have a db definition:

```
 items.hasMany(images, {as: 'images', foreignKey: 'itemID'});
```

When I'm creating an item like this ...

```
let result = await db.items.create(
      {
        type: req.body.type,
        name: req.body.name,
        images: [req.body.images]
      },
      {
        include: [ {model: db.images,  as: "images" } ]
      }
    );
```

... I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: instance.set is not a function

What could be the problem? Or it is not a correct way of insertion?

**SOLUTION**

The problem was in the type of object that I pass. I was passing [req.body.images], but it was already an array. So removing [] problem solved.

Thanks to everyone who checked it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = await db.items.create([
  {
    type: req.body.type,
    name: req.body.name,
    images: [req.body.images]
  },
  {
    include: [ {model: db.images,  as: "images" } ]
  }
]);
```

Wrap args with **array** in `create` function(). Hope it might help u.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't help. Only changed an error to the different one: TypeError: this.build(...).save is not a function

Comment: What I discovered as It needs to get a custom setter for the field. If I create it inside of the model - error goes away. But in that case, I don't know how manually target db.images from the model setter